# sound stops working after a while in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: sound, 12.10

i did a clean install on ubuntu 12.10. Everything seemed fine at first including sound but after a while it stopped working. To get is back i have to restart it, sometimes even more than once.

Any idea on how to fix this?

```
sudo aplay -L

default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC665 Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Same HDA Intel hardware. :(

Comment: I think this is [bug #1067434](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1067434).

Comment: See also [bug #1063965](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1063965).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had the same problem with no luck, got back to ubuntu 12.04 and everything was working fine

Comment: Can you confirm the bug at [bug #1063965](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1063965)?

Answer (score 6):

remove the `.pulse` directory and the file called `.pulse-cookie`  in your home folder;
then you need to logout for the change to take effect.

that's the way that I use most of the time.

Good luck.

Comment: Instead of logout, you can run `pkill pulse` from the command line.

Comment: Can you confirm this as [bug #1063965](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1063965)?

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.. :). Thanks @suruibin

Comment: this worked for me .. 

Card: HDA Intel PCH
Chip: Intel PantherPoint HDMI

Answer (score 1):

I used alsamixer and changed Auto-Mute Mode to Disabled

Answer (score 1):

First try changing `auto-mute mode` to `Disabled` in `alsamixer`, if still that doesn't work, please look at a detailed solution to this at [this link](http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/ubuntu-12-10-quantal-on-dell-xps-15-l502x/).

Answer (score 0):

see the AUDIO SOUND ISSUE in the link http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/ubuntu-12-10-quantal-on-dell-xps-15-l502x/